# Optimizing Options Portfolio

Tags: options, option-pricing, portfolio-optimization

I’m working on a model which creates a portfolio of options. The model has an alpha from an options trade for 1 period using several different underlying stocks. Would Mean Variance optimization still apply in this situation?

Comment: Does mean variance ever apply? Nassim Taleb for example argues that the theory is, in practice, [worthless](https://twitter.com/nntaleb/status/1127670292342611969?s=19).

Comment: Even *if* the underlying is multivariate normally distributed, the options will introduce a lot of higher moments (skewness and kurtosis), rendering MVO useless in most scenarios.

Comment: Given this, can these higher moments be accounted for in the optimization?